# Delete record from MySQL Using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

I am facing issues while trying to delete a record from my database.
I am getting this error : **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1**

```
app.post('/delete',function(req,res,next){
    var id= req.body.painting_id;
    console.log(req.body.painting_id);
    let sql = "DELETE FROM Paintings WHERE id = ?";

    connection.query(sql, (error, results, fields) => {
      if (error)
        return console.error(error.message);

      console.log('Deleted Row(s):', results.affectedRows);
        res.redirect('/admin/painting');
    });
})
```

This is my frontend part to delete

```
<form action="/delete" method="POST">
     <input type="text" name="painting_id" id="painting_id" >
     <input type="text" name="painting_title" id="painting_title" >
```

Comment: If you're not too committed to this style, it's worth checking out [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/master/) and using Promise-driven code instead. It makes error handling a lot easier. For example, you're doing it wrong here, that `return` in the `if (error)` clause is wrong, it fails to call `next()` and just leaves the request hanging.

Comment: Hint: If you're using placeholder values you *must supply the values* as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing only the statement with the placeholder but no the values for it.

From the documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-values

The correct way should be add the values for every placeholder you have in your statement like this:

```js
connection.query(sql, [id], (error, results, fields) => {
    if (error)
    return console.error(error.message);

    console.log('Deleted Row(s):', results.affectedRows);
    res.redirect('/admin/painting');
});
```

Note that it has to be an array, no matter how many values you have in your statement.